# Are there any non-trivial, efficient constructions of an infinite binary sequence whose initial $2^{n+1}$ bits provably contain all $n$-bit words?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am interested in constructing an infinite binary sequence $B$ that satisfies all of the following three properties:

1. For any $n$-bit word $w$ it is possible to *prove* that $w$ occurs as a substring (i.e., as a *contiguous* subsequence) in the initial $2^{n+1}$ bits of $B$;
2. $B$ is efficiently computable;
3. The construction is *not* based on the concatenation of de Bruijn sequences.

Without the third property, we can, for example, concatenate lexicographically first $2$-ary de Bruijn sequences of order $1,2,3,4$ etc. to obtain the infinite binary sequence

$$\text{01 0011 00010111 0000100110101111 } \ldots$$

which contains any $n$-bit word $w$ in its initial $2^{n+1}$ bits, but this is what I call a “trivial” construction here.

Question: are there constructions of such sequences that satisfy all of the three given properties?